# Ascensor.js and the scrollTop jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrolltop, ascensor

I am using ascensor.js on my website and I have a problem with jquery function scrollTop - it's doesn't work. I've tried different options but it still nothing happens. How to fix that?

// EDIT

Sorry. Here is the code.

I am using this simply function.

```
<a id="scrolltop"></a>

$(function () {
             $('#scrolltop').click(function () {
                 $('html, body').animate({
                     scrollTop: '0px'
                 },
                 1500);
                 return false;
             });
});
```

Now when I was included the [ascensor.js](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/ascensor) it's just stopped working anymore.

Comment: Post some code. Its not possible to say whats the issue. What error are you getting?

Comment: I've just added. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The one you have tried is normal jquery way, you are not using ascensor.js. Here is the both version and you can see the difference -

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.ascensor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Below is the body code, where for temporary I have used fixed 1000px to see scroll effect.

```
<div style="height:1000px;">Some text with fixed height</div>
<a id="scrolltop" style="float:right;width:100%" href="#">jquery-version</a>
<div style="height:20px;">&nbsp;</div>
<a id="ascensor" href="#">ascensor version</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    // attach jquery version to id scrolltop
    $('#scrolltop').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: '0px'
        },
        1500);
        return false;
    });

    // attach ascensor to id ascensor
    $('#ascensor').ascensor();

});
</script>
```

When you click on jquery-version thats not using ascensor and moves slowly as you are using animation. The other version is ascensor which by default do scroll top. The detail documentation and [implementation example](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/ascensor) can give you other capabilities to move in any direction animation.